# GRE percentages / discount question

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

The following is a practice question from a GRE preparation book.

A case of $100$ candy bars is sold at a discount of $\$0.36$ per bar.

**Quantity A:** the discount per case
**Quantity B:** 36%

(a) A is greater
(b) B is greater
(C) The two quantities are equal
(d) The relationship cannot be determined from the information given

---

My approach:
Quantity B is 36%, which is simply 0.36

Quantity A is 0.36 * 100 = 36

Therefore A > B.

However the answer I'm given is D. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: You don't know what a bar costs, so you don't know the *percent* discount.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the meaning of 'discount per case' clearly. Should not just mean the discount per 100 bars? Why is the % discount relevant?

Comment: Your answer would have been correct if **Quantity B** had said $\,\$0.36\,$, instead. But it does not, it says $\,36\%\,$, which is presumbaly to be interpreted as the *percent* discount off a box of candies.

Comment: Was subtle to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discount per case means the price after discount. However, the discount per case is the discounted amount divided by the total amount. Since only the discounted amount is known ($36), you cannot find the discount per case. Per case indicates that you know how much the case costs in the first place.

Comment: I am failing to understand how discount per case means the price after discount. How does 'discount per case' not mean 'discount per 100 bars', i.e. the total discount for 100 bars?

Comment: I think they want you to give it in terms of a percentage discount seeing that Quantity B is a percentage

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.